# How do I exclude a PHTML file within a CMS page from Magento's Full Page Cache?

Tags: magento-enterprise, cms, full-page-cache

Running Magento Enterprise v1.14.2.

I have a standard CMS page which contains a PHTML file (needed for a dynamic section of the page).

The PHTML is included in the CMS page like this:

```
{{block type="core/template" template="catalog/product/form-top.phtml"}}
```

Because the page is dynamic, I want to completely exclude it from Magento's Full Page Cache.

How do I do this?

*P.S. I've already tried using `<action method="setCacheLifetime"></action>` in the CMS Page -> Custom Layout XML section*